# uiwebview preventing access to buttons on uitoolbar

Tags: uiwebview, uibutton, uitoolbar

Am I thick or what? I have a view controller, and within that there is a UIWebView. When I run the app, the WebView covers the UIToolbar at the bottom and the UIButtons there, and so you cannot navigate away from the WebView. I cannot figure out how to change the WebView size or behaviour.

Unfortunately I do not have sufficient rep to post screenshots. The WebView displays an html file with text. The WebView partially covers the status bar at the top and completely covers the taskbar at the bottom. I can touch and drag the view up to see the taskbar and buttons at the bottom, but cannot use them.

I am using storyboard to build the app, and have done similar apps before without issue (in iOS6) but iOS7 appears to have thrown me a curveball.

I cannot see how to change the size in Xcode - or should I be looking at the html code in the file that the WebView is calling?

Comment: post code or screen shot relevant to that ....

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough this is no longer an issue, I have not made any changes to code or config, and the only thing different is I upgraded my version of X-Code